# If parallel transport from $p$ to $q$ does not depend on curve joining $p$ to $q$, then the curvature of $M$ is identically zero.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature, parametrization

I'm currently working through Do Carmo's book Riemannian Geometry and came across the following question:

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with the following property: given any two points $p, q \in M$, the parallel transport from $p$ to $q$ does not depend on the curve that joins $p$ to $q$. Prove that the curvature of $M$ is identically zero, that is, for all $X, Y, Z \in \chi(M), R(X, Y)Z = 0$.

He gives most of the proof for us, and I'm able to fill in most of the details, but I don't know why the highlighted part below follows. I imagine it's something easy that I've just forgotten about.

[Do Carmo, pg. 105](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcHFN.png)

Comment: Note that, by definition, a vector field $V$ is parallel along the curve if $\frac{DV}{ds}=0$.

Comment: Right, as Ernie just said. DoCarmo had just said that $V(s,1)$ was parallel along $f(s,1)$ as $0\le s\le 1$.